# Eclipse open resource dialog: How to order / sort the search results by project name?

Tags: eclipse

Using Eclipse 2018-09. In previous versions, the dialog used to sort the search results (matching items) by project name, now everything is random. Is there a new setting somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be Eclipse bug [539670](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539670)

The bug is marked as fixed in Eclipse core 4.10M1 (4.10 will be part of SimRel 2018-12).

Comment: Thank you! I actually did create that bug but couldn't find it anymore. Not in "My Bugs" and not through the Bugzilla search. Thought it was deleted / rejected.